# write SFMC [Script activity] [SSJS] object Properties to a DE

Tags: dataextensions, ssjs, object, properties

i my objective is to write object properties(Folder, DE , etc) to a DE , how can i achieve this?

here i tried, unsuccessfully, to write folderID to DE column ID , eventually i would like gather all properties and write them to DE. Appreciate your help, thank you.

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");

var myFolder= Folder.Retrieve({Property:"Name",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"Folder Script"});
var myFolderid = myFolder[0].ID;

var destDE = DataExtension.Init("DF6A178F-B0EC-40A6-B13D-9E3A5D5EA5EC"); 
// contains two fields ID number, Name (text 50)
destDE .Rows.Add({ ID: myFolderid } );

</script>
```